# How do I make errors about url-domsuf-parse-file go away?

Tags: eww

I am seeing it in connection with certain websites and eww.el.  Is there quick hack I can do to make those sites load?

The error I see is like the following:

```
error in process filter: url-domsuf-parse-file: Opening input file: \
no such file or directory, \
/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/publicsuffix.txt
```

I was using Aquamacs 3.2, the most recent at the time of writing.

Comment: Can you please include the actual text of the error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this might be a symptom of a bug in Aquamacs that has supposedly been fixed. See [this discussion](http://emacs.1067599.n5.nabble.com/aquamacs-devel-Re-quot-no-such-file-or-directory-quot-quot-Applications-Aquamacs-app-Contents-Resour-td311612.html)

It seems like the user in that post was able to solve the problem by running:

```
touch /Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/publicsuffix.txt
```

from the terminal to create the missing file. You can try this, our try creating the file from emacs by calling `C-x C-f` (`find-file`), entering the complete the path `/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/publicsuffix.txt` and confirming that you want to create the file which seems to be missing.

The issue is that the function `url-domsuf-parse-file` i[s expecting to find that file](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-release/blob/master/lisp/url/url-domsuf.el#L36), and it isn't where it should be. I am not sure what the consequences are of putting an empty file in its place, but it is worth a try. I guess you could even paste in the contents of [this file](https://github.com/davidswelt/aquamacs-emacs/blob/aquamacs3/etc/publicsuffix.txt), because I assume that is what it is looking for.

Finally, if you are using an outdated version of Aquamacs, you should update if possible, and the problem will likely fix itself.